# Problems with iOS 10.2 TV App?

Tags: video, ios, tv.app

[Edited for clarity and brevity]

The new TV app in iOS 10.2 is missing critical features of its predecessor Videos app.

The primary flaw is that there's no way to delete videos from within the app (see comments below for kludgey workaround).

Secondary flaws include removal of a "list" view (only "tiled" is available) and a bug in auto-rotate.

Does anyone else...

1. See the same problems?
2. Know how to fix them?
3. Or know of a 3rd party video player app (free or paid) that:
   a) Allows quick deletion of played videos from within the app?
   b) Provides list view of videos on device?
   c) Handles auto-rotate correctly?

Answer (score 0):

To delete a video:

- From Home Screen
- Tap Settings
- Tap General
- Tap Storage and iCloud Usage
- From Storage Tap Manage Storage
- Tap TV app

You will now see your videos in the app and at this point you can hit Edit and delete the videos you no longer want.

Shorter option:
Or you can click into the video and you'll see a Downloaded button.  Click that and you'll see the option to remove the video.

Comment: Good news: That worked.

Comment: Bad news: Horrible user experience.  I shouldn't have to do 7 actions to replace 2 actions (swipe > delete) in the previous Videos app.